# Dir() function "." and ".."

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working through someone else's bit of VBA code for cycling through files in a root directory and its subdirectories:

```vb
Public Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                             strFolder As String, _
                             strFileSpec As String, _
                             bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

     Dim strTemp As String
     Dim colFolders As New Collection
     Dim vFolderName As Variant

' Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles:

     strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
     strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)

     Do While strTemp <> vbNullString

         colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
         strTemp = Dir

     Loop

' Include Subfolders:

     If bIncludeSubfolders Then

     'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder

         strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)

         Do While strTemp <> vbNullString

             If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then

                 If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then

                     colFolders.Add strTemp

                 End If

             End If

             strTemp = Dir

         Loop

     'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders

         For Each vFolderName In colFolders

             Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)

         Next vFolderName

     End If

End Function
```

I've understood most of it, but I'm struggling a bit with how the Dir function works in some cases.

Specifically, the line that tests the following:

`If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then`

Seems to suggest that the preceding `strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)` could evaluate to "." or ".."

I can see why I wouldn't want them added to my collection, but what would the "." and ".." results from `Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)` indicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- '.' means the current directory
- '..' means the parent directory

They are returned by the 'dir' command. In your case (and any other I have seen) they just get in the way and so the code specifically ignores them

Comment: The underlying Win32 FindFirstFile API does this, thats where they bubble up from.

Comment: I presume they show in the command prompt's 'dir' command for the same reason.

Comment: So is "." and ".." listed as standard to make available information on the current and parent directory? I.e. "." and ".." in this case represent the current and parent directory, should you want some access to their attributes.

Comment: You can always reference a file in the current directory with .\file.txt or in the parent with ..\file.txt  I suspect they have been around for a long time and originate from Unix.